# using UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell. The collectionView cells are not drawn

Tags: objective-c

Using `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`. The `collectionView` cells drawn inside do not show on load. When scrolled/Dragged these `collectionViewCell` appear on row

Comment: Maybe this source code help you https://github.com/irfanlone/Collection-View-in-a-collection-view-cell

Comment: I think you need to reload data at some point